# How to flatten JSON before serializing?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Consider following JSON post request:

```
{
    "a":{
        "b": 1,
        "c": 1
     }
}
```

my model only has fields for `b` and `c`.
I need to flatten the JSON and serialize the following:

```
{
    "b": 1,
    "c": 2
}
```

I'm using serializers.ModelSerializer class to serialize:

```
class CardTransactionEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            "b",
            "c",
        ]
```

view:

```
class MyListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = models.MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MySerializer
```

model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    b = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, )
    c = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, )
```

I don't care about the `a` I just need to serialize what is inside of it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what `a`, `b` and `c` are here. `a` is a charfield, so how can it contain `b` which is also a field?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right, that was my mistake, just edited it to make it more sensible. I care about b and c, which are the model CharFields.

Comment: But that is what this will give you. I'm really not understanding your question. Are you perhaps talking about deserializing rather than serializing?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was using the term "serializing" interchangeably with "deserializing", but yes, going from json -> model